# Disable evolutions for a specific database in Play2?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, anorm

When using several connections in a Play2 app, is it possible to disable the evolutions part of the framework for a specific connection?

EDIT : A [ticket](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401-play-20/tickets/597-evolutions-is-enabled-by-default-on-all-existing-database-connections) has been created.

Comment: You put your evolutions in the `default` folder so only the default connection uses evolutions. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, even in the other databases, Play creates the "play_evolutions" table which I would like to avoid.

Comment: Ah right, they are creating a table if none is available but don't check for scripts. You should file a [ticket](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401-play-20/overview).

Comment: Created a ticket. If you transform your comment to an answer I'll accept it. @MariusSoutier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The evolutions helper is creating a table if none is available, but doesn't check if any scripts are defined for that connection. You should file a [ticket](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401-play-20/overview).